# Does python's 'format' round up float?

Tags: python, floating-point, format

I was solving some problem from compatitive programming and a part of the thing it asked was:

> 'truncate return value at floating two chiphers'(sorry I'm not a native english speaker) like 3.296 -> 3.29 (anyway, what is the correct english expression for this?)

So, first, I did some simple parsing :

```py
c = some_float_value
stred = str(c)
stred = stred[:stred.find('.') + 3]
if len(stred)-2 == stred.find('.'):
    stred += '0'
```

Seemed like it was working fine, but my solution was rejected.

So I tried 'format' instead:

```py
c = some_float_value
formated = format(c, '.2f')
```

Which resulted in acceptance.

Thought about my first code but couldn't find any anomaly as long as `c` being a `float` value.

So built following test where random float value is compared using two different methods presented above:

```py
import random

while True:
    c = random.random()

    stred = str(c)
    stred = stred[:stred.find('.') + 3]
    if len(stred)-2 == stred.find('.'):
        stred += '0'

    formated = format(c, '.2f')

    if stred != formated:
        print(c, stred, formated)
        break
```

Result is interesting. For example, when `c` is `0.006799844470375294`, my methods returns `0.00` while `format` returns `0.01`.

My question is - why is it so? I assume `format` doesn't do rounding thus 'rounding like behaviour' is more related to 'floating point precision' problem. Or am I thinking it worng?

Comment: `format` rounds because it is converting a floating point number to a [fixed point number](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/fixed-point-and-floating-point-number-representations) with 2 decimal places (which is what you call this in English BTW), so it is giving you the 2-decimal fixed point number nearest to your input. Your method just truncates the string, so it will always match the digits of the input.

Comment: So it actually rounds the number ! Thank you for answering.